# SmartPy Contract: Receive a balance?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I'm learning SmartPy and I'm trying to make a simple escrow contract. I read that `contract.balance` can be used to access the balance of a contract. In that case, how would I go about receiving XTZ to the contract's balance and sending it from the contract's balance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To receive XTZ, you simply avoid refusing it: you need an entry_point that will simply accept XTZ by literally not sending an exception.

You can see the number of XTZ sent by looking at `sp.amount`.

To send XTZ, you need to use either `sp.send` for simple XTZ transfers or `sp.transfer` for general transfers.

See https://smartpy.io/reference.html#_contracts_and_addresses for the details.

Comment: What if many people send XTZ at the same time? How would I distinguish between the different amounts that people send?

Comment: With any transaction to any of your entry points, you have parameters so you may require your users to send this information and you also have access to the sender with `sp.sender`.

Comment: This is my deposit function: https://pastebin.com/gvZcp8jX. Does calling an entry point initiate a transaction?

Comment: Yes. Calling an entry point is synonymous to sending a transaction to the contract.

Comment: Thanks! So that means the amount of XTZ sent when calling an entry point can be customised?